# How to get place description from AutocompleteSupportFragment in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, google-places-autocomplete

I am trying to get the address of a place using AutocompleteSupportFragment. Like in the screen shot below, If I select Indianapolis, I need to get both the name and the address below ("IN, USA").

[image]

I have succeeded in getting the name but the address returns null.

Ihave tried several ways like

```
 AddressComponents addressComponents = place.getAddressComponents();

                    List<AddressComponent> addressComponentList = addressComponents.asList(); //The size of this is 0. SO I dont't get anything from this.

                for (AddressComponent pla : addressComponentList) {
                    Log.d("fferfe", pla.getShortName());
                }
```

I have also tried this

```
 Log.d("fferfe", place.getAddress());
```

The above crashes as I cannot Log an null value. The result of  place.getAddress() is null.

How can I get the address details?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer myself.

I provided address as one of the parameters I needed.

```
     autocompleteFragmentOrigin.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME,Place.Field.ADDRESS));
```

instead of

```
autocompleteFragmentOrigin.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));
```